# Android - Saving data to an internal storage

Tags: java, android, android-activity, internal-storage

I'm working on a simple to-do list app, and I'm trying to read/write data from/to internal storage. I'm trying to understand when exactly those read/write methods should be called.

I know that the activity class has an `onCreate()` method which will be a reasonable location for my read method, but where should I call my write method?

I want to call it when the app closes/ends, so I'd assume `onDestory()` is a good location, but i heard that `onDestroy()` may not be a good location for data storage operations and i should use `onStop()`.

Any help or ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Following the table in the Android Developers Guide on the [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle), your app may be killed by the system any time without warning  after either `onPause()` (for Pre-HONEYCOMB devices) or after `onStop()`. So you probably want to write your data in these methods to make sure nothing gets lost. So for newer devices (API level 11 and up), `onStop()` should be fine. If your app should run on older devices as well, `onPause()` would be the best place.

Comment: Would it be better to read from storage in onCreate() or onStart() if I use onStop() to write the data?

Comment: Depends. If your data can be changed externally, you might need to put this in `onStart()`. Otherwise, `onCreate()` should be fine. If your app is killed by the system, `onCreate()` will be invoked when the app is called again. If it is not killed by the system, your previously read data should still be loaded, so no need to read again. (Unless the data is changed externally. In this case, you may need to read it more often than in `onStart()`, e.g., providing a user button or checking for changes periodically.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on Application Lifecycle.

[image: This Picture]

And see [This](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/processes/process-lifecycle.html).

`onStop()` invokes when user press home button(Hard Key).

And then, if memory insufficient or another reason, Android Memory Manager will kill your app instant and `onDestory()` will never called.

The best thing you have to is make a button to save datas. Of course, Include `onStop()` save routine.

Comment: Would it be better to read from storage in onCreate() or onStart() if I use onStop() to write the data?

Answer (score -1):

This is Just sample code. But you get the idea. Create a custom method implementing the code below and call it on some events like "onClick" or any other.

```
File file;
    FileOutputStream strem = null;
    String line = "Hey this is my name";
    try {
        file = new File("sdcard/newFile.txt");
        strem = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] bytes = line.getBytes();
        strem.write(bytes);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            strem.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```